# Как выполнить поиск по ключевому слову не используя браузер?

Tags: python, php, node.js, firebase, google-search

Наткнулся на вот такую старую статью про [Google поиск](https://habr.com/ru/company/crossover/blog/432296/) Задался вопросом, а возможно ли делать "запросы" по ключевым словам, но не используя браузер? Если точнее, существует ли программа, на любом серверном языке, которая будет делать запрос и возвращать скажем топ 10 ссылок на сайты по этому ключу из поиска google.com по установленным параметрам? Если кто-то в тема, можете посоветовать в каком направлении искать? *Предпочтительно для Node JS

Comment: Может подойдёт что-то из этого [npm i google-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-it),  [npm i google-search-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-search-scraper)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [Programmable Search Engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search) или [Yandex.XML](https://yandex.ru/dev/xml/)